# Show Prompt in Spinner when activity is resumed

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner

I have a spinner in my activity which is loaded with the database values. First time when the activity is loaded the spinner is selected to show the prompt text. When i go to the next activity and press back button then the spinner is selected to show the first item. But i need to show the prompt text when the activity is resumed.

How to achieve that? I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Plz post your first activities info (code and xml).  This would help us give an accurate answer.

However,  if you programmatically set your spinner with :

```
mSpinner.setSelection(0); // or whatever index you want to revert to
```

BEFORE you start up your 2nd activity.  You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done, to make spinner show the prompt text, do it in:
`onResume` method (Override it).

Also, if the thing that causes the spinner to show prompt text, is something that is not set yet, and you set it later(somewhere in onCreate, so it wont re-show it again in future),
you can override also `onPause`, to unset it.

[Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) is the key!